# Why can't I write a udev rule using NAME or PRODUCT?

Tags: linux, udev, bluetooth

I would like to write a udev rule that would trigger when I connect my Bose headphones via bluetooth.

After running `udevadm monitor --kernel --property` and connecting my headphones I get this:

```
KERNEL[2226.084251] add      /devices/virtual/input/input22 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/input/input22
SUBSYSTEM=input
PRODUCT=5/9e/4020/452
NAME="Słuchawencje (AVRCP)"
PHYS="00:0d:f0:bf:f7:df"
PROP=0
EV=100007
KEY=2fc800 145200000000 0 10300 49e800000c00 e16800000000f f810000010000ffc
REL=0
MODALIAS=input:b0005v009Ep4020e0452-e0,1,2,14,k71,72,73,8A,8B,A3,A5,A6,A7,A8,AB,AE,C8,C9,D0,161,164,166,16A,16C,18B,18E,18F,190,191,192,193,195,ramlsfw
SEQNUM=3814
```

But then when I run `udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/devices/virtual/input/input22` the NAME and the PRODUCT are not there:

```
  looking at device '/devices/virtual/input/input22':
    KERNEL=="input22"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{uniq}==""
    ATTR{phys}=="00:0d:f0:bf:f7:df"
    ATTR{properties}=="0"
```

Why? Why can't I use the NAME/PRODUCT in the udev rule?

For other bluetooth devices, such as my wireless speaker, udev behaves slightly better. This is the output of `udevadm monitor --kernel --property` for my wireless speaker:

```
KERNEL[2635.676303] add      /devices/virtual/input/input23 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/input/input23
SUBSYSTEM=input
PRODUCT=5/0/0/0
NAME="JBL GO 2 (AVRCP)"
PHYS="00:0d:f0:bf:f7:df"
PROP=0
EV=100007
KEY=2fc800 145200000000 0 10300 49e800000c00 e16800000000f f810000010000ffc
REL=0
MODALIAS=input:b0005v0000p0000e0000-e0,1,2,14,k71,72,73,8A,8B,A3,A5,A6,A7,A8,AB,AE,C8,C9,D0,161,164,166,16A,16C,18B,18E,18F,190,191,192,193,195,ramlsfw
SEQNUM=3834
```

And `udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/devices/virtual/input/input23` prints:

```
  looking at device '/devices/virtual/input/input23':
    KERNEL=="input23"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{name}=="JBL GO 2 (AVRCP)"
    ATTR{properties}=="0"
    ATTR{uniq}==""
    ATTR{phys}=="00:0d:f0:bf:f7:df"
```

The PRODUCT is still not there but at least the NAME is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a device property in a rule you have to use for example:

```
ENV{PRODUCT}
```

There are only so many [default properties](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v245/src/udev/udev-rules.c#L613). The rest are device specific and ENV{PROPERTY} is the way to reference them.

Comment: Thanks, that works for PRODUCT! What about NAME? `ENV{NAME}=="..."` does not seem to work.

Comment: I think ATTR{NAME} should work, but I've not used it so far.